# Is there any rule preventing me from starting multiple bardic performances in a single round?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, bard, move-action

Bardic Performance reads as follows:

> Starting a bardic performance is a standard action, but it can be
>   maintained each round as a free action. Changing a bardic performance
>   from one effect to another requires the bard to stop the previous
>   performance and start a new one as a standard action. A bardic
>   performance cannot be disrupted, but it ends immediately if the bard
>   is killed, paralyzed, stunned, knocked unconscious, or otherwise
>   prevented from taking a free action to maintain it each round. A bard
>   cannot have more than one bardic performance in effect at one time.
>
> At 7th level, a bard can start a bardic performance as a move action
>   instead of a standard action. At 13th level, a bard can start a bardic
>   performance as a swift action.

I'm going to play a Sound Striker and my plan is to use Weird Words an offensive bardic performance as a standard action and then use Inspire Courage to buff my party as a movement action.

Is that possible? Is there any rule that prevents me from starting more than 1 bardic performance per round?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### 7th level bards

All bards, from 7th level on, can start a new performance as a *Move Action*. From then on, you *can* either use a standard or a move action to start a performance, and thus start two different performances in a single round.

> At 7th level, a bard can start a bardic performance as a move action instead of a standard action. At 13th level, a bard can start a bardic performance as a swift action.

At 13th, you should be able to start up to three different performances in a round, using your standard, move and swift actions.

Do note that you can only have one bardic performance in effect at any given time. So, normally, you couldn't have *Inspire Courage* and *Inspire Competence* active simultaneously, as you have to stop one performance before you start another.

> A bard cannot have more than one bardic performance in effect at one time.

However, you are not *in fact* using two performances simultaneously, as the [Sound Striker](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/bard/archetypes/paizo-bard-archetypes/sound-striker/)'s *Weird Words* ability is not a bardic performance that lasts for a number of rounds. It is a supernatural ability that *"consumes"* your daily uses of bardic performance, create a magical effect, and dissipates. In other words, the *Weird Word* performance is like an instantaneous effect, it begins and ends immediately.

Just remember that *Weird Words* is "always a standard action" to use.

### Mythic Bards

[Mythic](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/mythic/) bard characters who take the [Marshal](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/mythic/mythic-heroes/mythic-paths-paizo-inc/marshal/) mythic path may learn the *Lightning Performance* ability, which allows them to start a new performance as a *Swift Action* instead of a *Standard Action*:

> **Lightning Performance** (Ex): Your tongue is as quick as any blade. You can start a bardic performance as a **swift action** instead of a standard action. If you expend one use of mythic power, you can instead start a bardic performance as a free action.

Using this ability would allow you to start two performances in the same round *before* you are 7th level, one using your standard action and another using your swift action, as mythic paths follow a different progression from normal character advancement. Meaning that you could be a first level bard with a mythic tier 1 and this ability to start performances as a swift action.